# Download Excel data using python

Tags: python

I would like to use python to download data from this link:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962

Then turn this data into dataframe.

I don't think my code is working.

Can you please help me to do it?

Thank you,
Hong

```
query_string = 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962'
df = pd.ExcelFile(query_string)
print(type(df))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Harry Well, I was not able to download this data through python, but this data can be read directly and then can be converted to dataframe which can also be saved as an excel file as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962')
data.to_excel(name.xlsx)#Name of the file in which you want this data to get stored
```